# Germany Tourist Schengen Visa application as remote employee for US Company

Tags: visa, schengen

I'm Software engineer working remotely within an US Company. I'm planning to visit Germany in holiday for about 5 days , but I'm not sure if I will get my Schengen Visa because of my work type, since I have applied before for UK visa and they refused to grant me the the visa because my work did not approve that I would come back to my home country. I usually withdraw my earning in different dates , I don't do that at the end of each month, which means my bank statements will show different income amount in random dates.  Any idea guys or suggestion, so make my visa application more powerful .

Comment: Where do you live?  What do you mean by "my work did not approve that I would come back to my home country"?

Comment: I live in morocco ."my work did not approve that I would come back to my home country" I'm working remotely with a company located in USA, so there is nothing that could prove that will come back to home .

Comment: I don't think Schengen visa is much related to your current work type? As long as you prove you have sufficient economic means it should be fine? And also if you're still a formal employee of the company with some kind of contract, you can still show the contract?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @xiang-ji above

Since you would be a tourist, just apply for a tourist visa and don't confuse the situation any more than you need to - thus if asked are you employed, then the answer is yes. Do you have funds to cover your stay, answer is yes. Who do you work for? Give the name of the US company (chances are, Shengen will not know that the US company do not have an office in Morocco - don't state unless asked). Proof of salary/income? Provide bank statements or pay slips. If having a face to face interview, relax, smile, be calm. They are not trying to trick you out. Their only concern is that you are not a burden or risk to society so if you have your own money and you are not bringing trouble, you have nothing to worry about.

Oh! The UK is not Shengen, so your experience there does not effect your application here.

If they ask, always be truthful as lie's can reveal doubts, and an officer will pick up on this at your cost.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @fiprojects,
Thanks for your response , yes have all the documents that proves that I can support myself , but the question is that , they may check my employment contract , then they will know that the company is not located in morocco . but will give it a try . thanks anyway guys .
Regards

Comment: Best of luck. Be confident/clear and avoid being evasive or they will think you are hiding something. There are many far shore workers these days, they might ask to know more about it, but only to fill their own curiosity.

Comment: yes that's far enough , thanks you so much for the advice.